# date_format function for 'YYYYMM' format gives wrong result

Tags: hive

I'm trying to change the formatting of ownshp_start_dt  as 'YYYYMM' but getting the wrong output in some obesrvations.

```
SELECT ownshp_start_dt,date_format(ownshp_start_dt,'YYYYMM') from test;
```

Output :

[image]

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the format to `SELECT ownshp_start_dt,date_format(ownshp_start_dt,'yyyyMM') from test;` (please note lower case for year segment).